# global creator,timespan on any insert query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

is there a way to hack codeigniter to let it by default when doing any insert/update inserts that timespan and user_id into a specific columns in table ?

i have 8 tables in database, all contain (update_time,updated_by)columns , i want to set codeigniter active records so that when ever and update/insert is occuring it automaticly populate `update_time=time() and update_by=$this->session->userdata('user')->id;`

also on same concept i want to hack delete action into updating column(archived)=1 instead of deleting (since my mysql user doesnt have delete record access anyway)

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hack CI to accomplish this you should look in the system/drivers/DB_Active_rec.php (given that you use the active record functionality in CI)

For example, you can insert the current time on an update by modifying the update method in that file. Change this:

```
public function update($table = '', $set = NULL, $where = NULL, $limit = NULL)
{
    // Combine any cached components with the current statements
    $this->_merge_cache();

    if ( ! is_null($set))
    {
        $this->set($set);
    }
            [...]
```

into:

```
public function update($table = '', $set = NULL, $where = NULL, $limit = NULL)
{
    // Combine any cached components with the current statements
    $this->_merge_cache();

    // start of Insert updated_time hack
    $time_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    $set['update_time'] = date($time_format);
    // end of hack

    if ( ! is_null($set))
    {
        $this->set($set);
    }
            [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing [functionality of mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html) to auto update the `update_time` column when a record is inserted or updated. However, updating the `user_id` is something you would have to do manually from your application.

Your other requirement is generally referred to as a *soft delete* by some, where you mark a row as deleted by turning a flag on a column. This is possible, but you have to make sure that all your select and update queries are avoiding rows with this flag turned on.

It is best that you carefully construct your Model methods to adhere to these two requirements of the application. You can perhaps maks use of [extending the core Model](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) of CI to have a customised update / select queries that will be used by all child classes that extends MY_Model.

Comment: That *is* my description of *HOW* to do it. I can't write half of your application - what has been tried so far?